# Failover to 2nd HDD on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have a system with two hard drives.  Ubuntu installed on one and Debian on the other.  Recently, the cable connector to the Ubuntu drive became loose and the P.C. did not boot.  How can I make the computer fail over to the Debian drive if the Ubuntu drive is not found?  If the Ubuntu drive is found, then GRUB shows both Debian and Ubuntu options at boot.  If the Ubuntu drive is not found, then the P.C. displays Grub Rescue > prompt.
I would like to copy my GRUB installation to the second hard drive so it can boot to Debian if the Ubuntu drive was down.
Is there a dd command or scp command I can use, or do I have to go through a grub installation with the Ubuntu drive disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install grub on the other drive, but you don't have to do it with the Ubuntu drive disconnected. You can run

`grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sdX /dev/sdX`

(Where /mnt/sdX is where the second drive is mounted and /dev/sdX is the second drive)

to install grub on second drive from Ubuntu. You'll also want to make sure your bios will boot from the second drive if the first is missing.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll take those steps and also check my bios settings first.  It might just be that my bios isn't set to boot from the other drive.  I think I did install grub on both drives back when I set this machine up.  It's been a while, and I'm an old fart who has his mind backed up on a floppy somewhere, but I can't find the floppy.